# Elasticsearch "size" value not working in terms aggregation with partitions

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to paginate over a specific field using the terms aggregation with partitions.
The problem is that the number of returned terms for each partition is not equal to the size parameter that I set.

These are the steps that I am doing:

1. Retrieve the number of different unique values for the field with "cardinality" aggregation.
   In my data, the result is 21.
2. From the web page, the user wants to display a table with 10 items per page.

   ```
   if unique_values % page_size != 0:
           partitions_number = (unique_values // page_size) + 1
       else:
           partitions_number = (unique_values // page_size)
   ```

Than I am making this simple query:

```
POST my_index/_search?pretty
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field_to_paginate": "foo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_pchostname": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "field": "field_to_paginate",
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting to retrieve 10 results. But if I run the query I have only 7 results.
What am I missing here? Do I need to use a different solution here?

As a side note, I can't use composite aggregation because I need to sort results by doc_count over the whole dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitons in terms aggregation divide the values in equal chunks.

In your case no of partition `num_partitions` is 3 so 21/3 == 7.

Partitons are meant for getting large values in the order of 1000 s.

Comment: They are not divided in equal chunks. I had 3.5M items and with 100,000 partitions, size of buckets varied from 25 to 41. The terms aggregation is meant to return the top terms and does not allow pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to leverage `shard_size` parameter. My suggestion is to [read this part of manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts) and work with the shard_size param

Answer (score 0):

Terms aggregation does not allow pagination. Use composite aggregation instead (requires ES >= 6.1.0). Below is the quote from [reference docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size):

> If you want to retrieve all terms or all combinations of terms in a
> nested terms aggregation you should use the Composite aggregation
> which allows to paginate over all possible terms rather than setting a
> size greater than the cardinality of the field in the terms
> aggregation. The terms aggregation is meant to return the top terms
> and does not allow pagination.

Comment: Hi @kundan, but why does it not honour the "size" value? Can you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214253/elasticserch-terms-aggregation-with-partition-does-not-honor-the-size-value It always does without partitions