# Elasticserch terms aggregation with partition does not honor the "size" value

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a nested field in the ES index. I used the cardinality aggregation to get the total number of buckets and then came up with num_partitions, and size values to fetch the buckets.

E.g. the total number of term buckets = 761

Used num_partitions = 4, size = 200

But this returns me the following number of buckets in the 4 requests = 200, 194, 176, 165
Which sums to 735 < 761.

Now when using num_partitions = 3, size = 300

The 3 requests returned the following number of buckets = 246, 261, 254
Which sums to 761.

The second case did not miss any buckets but still, I would expect it to go like this = 300, 300, 161.

So, the questions are -

- Why did the first choice of num_partitions and size miss 26 buckets?
- Why is not honouring the "size" value in either of the above scenarios?

**NOTE -**

- ES version = 5.6.1. Upgrading to ES 6 is not possible in near future. Hence can not consider using composite aggregation.
- I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411594/elasticsearch-size-value-not-working-in-terms-aggregation-with-partitions) old question and one of the answer quotes the ES documentation that "The terms aggregation is meant to return the top terms and does not allow pagination." But I still do not understand why does it not return buckets in 300, 300, 161 numbers in the case 2 above. Without using partitions, it has always honoured the "size" value.

In case required, here is the aggregation part of the query -

```
"aggregations":{
"aggs":{
  "nested":{
    "path":"software"
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "bool":{
          "must":[
            {
              "match_phrase_prefix":{
                "sw.publisher":{
                  "query":"O",
                  "slop":100,
                  "max_expansions":50,
                  "boost":1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative":true,
          "boost":1.0
        }
      },
      "aggregations":{
        "host_sw":{
          "terms":{
            "field":"sw.hostId",
            "size":200,
            "min_doc_count":1,
            "shard_min_doc_count":0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error":false,
            "order":[
              {
                "_count":"desc"
              },
              {
                "_term":"asc"
              }
            ],
            "include":{
              "partition":3,
              "num_partitions":4
            }
          }
        },
        "sw_host_id.total_count":{
          "cardinality":{
            "field":"sw.hostId",
            "precision_threshold":20000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}